# Propagation of error for not-analytical calculable inverse function

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, inverse

I have the function:

```
gcsymb[Lpd_,a_,c_]:=1 /finv[1./Lpd^2,a,c]/Lpd
```

with the definiton of finv:

```
f[x_,a_,c_] := a* ((x-1+Exp[-x])-Exp[-2*c*x]*(-x-1+Exp[x]));

finv[Lpd_,a_,c_] :=
 InverseFunction[f,1,3][Lpd,a,c]
```

a and c are fit parameter. In order to calculate the Error of the maximum in gcsymb, i need an expression like Lpd_max[a_,c_], which is derivable with repect to a and c...

But i am stuck at

```
Lpd_max[a_,c_] := Solve[gcsymb[Lpd,a,c]==0,Lpd]
```

Because Mathematica says:

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained...

Any Ideas?

MfG

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Lpd_max will not work see [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)

Answer (score 1):

Even with the necessary correction by Lou, `Solve` cannot solve functions like `gcsymb`.  More promising options are `NSolve` and `FindRoot`, although they must be provided numerical values for `a` and `b`.  However, neither gives an answer, because `gcsymb` is ill-behaved for `Ldp` very near `0`, which is the solution to the calculation for `c >= 1/2`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[gcsymb[Lpd, a, c], {a, 0, 4, 2}, {c, 0, 4, 2}]], {Lpd, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: `InverseFunction` misbehavior**

For `c >= 1/2`, `gcsymb` passes through zero at `Lpd == 0`.  For `c < 1/2`, on the other hand, `gcsymb` does not equal zero for any real value of `Lpd`.

In order for `NSolve` and `FindRoot`, to find the root of `gcsymb` at `Lpd == 0`, `gcsymb` must be well behaved there.  Consider a few cases.

```
gcsymb[.001, 2, 1]
(* 0.002 *)
gcsymb[.0001, 2, 1]
(* 10000./InverseFunction[f, 1, 3][1.*10^8, 2, 1] *)
```

`finv[1.*10^8, 2, 1]` is returning unevaluated.

The actual inverse function of `f[x, 2, 1]` can be plotted without difficulty using `ParametricPlot` (shown in blue).  We compare this with a plot of `finv[Lpd, 2, 1]` (shown in red).

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[{f[x, 2, 1], x}, {x, 0, 2 10^6}, 
          WorkingPrecision -> 20, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
      Plot[finv[Lpd, 2, 1], {Lpd, 0, 10^7}, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

That `InverseFunction` fails at large `Lpd` is surprising, since the actual inverse function is approximately `Lpd / a` there.  This observation leads to the following work-around.  Redefine

```
finv[Lpd_, a_, c_] := If[Abs[Lpd] < 10000, InverseFunction[f, 1, 3][Lpd, a, c], Lpd/a]
gcsymb[Lpd_, a_, c_] := If[Lpd != 0, 1/finv[1/Lpd^2, a, c]/Lpd, 0]
```

Then

```
Lpdmax[2, 1]
(* {{Lpd -> 0}} *)
```

`FindRoot` and `Reduce` also give the right answer.  In  fact, now even `Solve` gives the right answer.